# Set debug JVM args on specific gradle task

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I've got the following gradle (version 2.3) task defined

```
task local {
    tasks.withType(org.springframework.boot.gradle.run.BootRunTask) {
        systemProperty('spring.profiles.active', 'local')
    }
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = [
            "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to start a spring boot application with debugging enabled.

For some reason this does not work from inside the local task:

```
> No such property: applicationDefaultJvmArgs for class: org.gradle.api.DefaultTask_Decorated
```

Answer (score 2):

`applicationDefaultJvmArgs` is a property of the 'application' plugin. That plugin was probably not applied in your project, so the property does not exist in your `local` task.

Comment: I've applied the plugin but still it doesn't do what I expect it to do. I'm using task wrong it should be task local << { .. but then applicationDefaultJvmArgs isn't set anymore